# How can i listen for http requests on a client side

Tags: javascript

The logic of my code is basic.
The user sends a request to the server side, where it is processed and shown in an admin panel. Afterwards a person with access to the admin panel analyses the data and sends a response with some delay.

How can I create a response listener on the client side, so that I can catch the message I get from back-end, no matter the delay?
I tried doing it with fetch, but no wonder it didn't work, because once it is compiled, it makes the action immediately. Is AJAX an option in my case?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Comment: Do you mean a callback function or `await` handler on a promise?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to make Javascript's fetch() wait for response, even if response takes an hour to return, without making a second request attempt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51783968/is-it-possible-to-make-javascripts-fetch-wait-for-response-even-if-response)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to have some sort of bidirectional communication layer here. The most common approaches are [polling](https://javascript.info/long-polling), [web hooks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-a-webhook-and-how-to-use-it/), or [sockets](https://socket.io). Polling will probably be the easiest to set up in a beginner use-case.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to jQuery's `$.ajax`, which uses XMLHttpRequest, it's not likely to be a good idea unless the server can respond *very* quickly every time. From what I understand, if the request isn't fulfilled within a [reasonably short period of time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42799434), the browser or OS will terminate it. Fetch might have different limitations, but I still wouldn't trust it for something like this.

There are better approaches. Either create a [websocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API), so that the server can push information to the client on demand, or (less elegant) have the client repeatedly make requests to the server (say, every minute)  and have the server respond positively if/when the admin panel has been dealt with.